# I am unable to solve the fractional knapsack problem using greedy algorithm in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, knapsack-problem, greedy

**Problem Description** : - Maximizing the Value of the Loot Problem Find the maximal value of items that fit into the backpack.

Input: The capacity of a back- pack W as well as the weights (w 1 , . . . , w n ) and per
pound prices(p 1 , . . . , p n ) of n different compounds.

Output: The maximum total priceof items that fit into the backpackof the given capacity:
i.e.,the maximum value of p 1 · u 1 + · · · + p n · u n such that u 1 + · · · + u n ≤ W
and 0 ≤ u i ≤ w i for all i.

Input format -  The first line of the input contains the number n of com-
pounds and the capacity W of a backpack. The next n lines define
the prices and weights of the compounds. The i-th line contains the
price per pound p i and the weight w i of the i-th compound.

Output format - Output the maximum price of compounds that fit into
the backpack.

Here is my Code:-

```
b = []                              # list
n = input().split()                 # number of elements here
total_weight = int(n[1])            # total_weight
times = int(n[0])                   # No of things
for i in range(times):
    item = [int(x) for x in input().split()]          # 10 50   - price weight
    per  = float(item[0])/float(item[1])              # per = 10/50 
    item.insert(0,per)
    b.append(item)                                    # list
b.sort(reverse = True)                            # sort on the basis of per
value = 0
for i in range(times):
    if b[i][2] >= total_weight:     # b[i] = [2,100,50]  total_weight = 20
        value = value + (b[i][0] * total_weight) # 2 * 20 = 40
    if b[i][2] < total_weight:
        value = value + (b[i][0] * b[i][2])    #b[i] = [5,50,10] total_weight = 20   5*10     
    if value == total_weight:
        break
    total_weight = total_weight - b[i][2]
print(round(value,4))
```

I am unable to get correct answers in some cases .. do review my code if any logical errors are there

Answer (score 0):

Input values `price per pound p i` already are sorting keys, so introducing `per` variable and corresponding field of `item / b[]` seems wrong.

---

Also note that here

```
if value == total_weight:
```

you compare float value for exact equality - it is not quite correct, because you can get result like `27.000000000001` due to limited precision.

It is worth to make comparison with some tolerance level using `math.isclose` function. And you can just remove this comparison, adding break in the first if-block

Comment: that helped .. also adding break after the 1st if made logic much better